$[\forall H\le G,gH=Hg] \to g\in Z(G)$
Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. If $gH=Hg$ for every subgroup $H\le G$ then $g\in Z(G)$?
Approach: Let $x\in G$, consider the subgroup $H=\langle x\rangle$, then $gx=x^ng$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$,
but it can be shown that $n=1$?
Approach: $\varphi_g:H\to H$, $\varphi_{g}(h)=ghg^{-1}$ is an isomorphism.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Hint: this is true for all groups of order $\leq 7$, but...

The statement is false.
Let $G=Q_8$, the quaternion group.  Then every proper subgroup is either central or has index $2$, so every proper subgroup is normal.  Thus, $\forall g \in G, H \le G~(gH=Hg)$.  But $Q_8$ is not abelian so it has non-central elements.  Thus, the claim fails for $Q_8$.
